# python programming using codeskulptor: simple calculator using simplegui

Tags: python, calculator, python-2.x, codeskulptor

This is my python code where I'm trying to create a simple calculator in [CodeSkulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org/) using [SimpleGUI](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#simplegui-create_frame) functions.
Even though I've defined `input1` and `input2`
I'm ending up with an error:

```
Line 22: NameError: name 'input2' is not defined
```

Please help me.
Thank you

```
import simplegui
#initialize globals
def input_handler1(text_input1):
    global input1
    input1=float(text_input1)
    output()
def input_handler2(text_input2):
    global input2
    input2=float(text_input2)
    output()
def button_handler():
    print inp1.get_text
def button_handler():
    print inp2.get_text

def output():
"""prints contents of input1 and input2"""
    print("input1=",input1)
    print("input2=",input2)
    print (" ")

def swap():
"""swap the contents of input1 and input2"""
    global input1,input2
    input1,input2=input2,input1
    output()
def add():
    global input1,input2
    input1+=input2
    output()
def sub():
    global input1,input2
    input1-=input2
    output()
def mul():
    global input1,input2
    input1*=input2
    output() 
def div():
    global input1,input2
    input1/=input2
    output()    

frame=simplegui.create_frame("simple_calculator",500,500)

inp1 = frame.add_input('input1', input_handler1, 50)
inp2 = frame.add_input('input2', input_handler2, 50)

frame.add_button("Print",output,100)
frame.add_button("swap",swap,100)
frame.add_button("add",add,100)
frame.add_button("subtract",sub,100)
frame.add_button("multiply",mul,100)
frame.add_button("divide",div,100)
frame.start()
```

Comment: I don't know `simplegui`, so I'm just guessing, but did you enter some numbers into `inp1` and `inp2` before clicking one of the buttons? BTW, it would be better to put this into a class so that you don't need to use `global`.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of docstrings are wrong. And we need to declare `input1` and `input2`.

Here the corrected code (with some other cosmetic change to respect the PEP 8):
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user45_G2dN41wx9eUEWCd.py

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning 
Input1=0
Input2=0
Solves the problem.
I could fix the issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using global variables anyway